# SQL: Query returns count of records with specific value as a column

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW P.ID, First(I.Type) AS [First Of Type], Count(*) AS [Count Of I]
FROM P INNER JOIN I ON P.[ID] = I.[P ID]
GROUP BY P.ID;
```

Where the types are "a" and "b". My query will return:

```
ID         First of Type         Count of I
1          a                     6
```

This is great but what I'd like is:

```
ID         First of Type         Count of I        Count of a        Count of b
1          a                     6                 2                 4
```

I can't figure out how to make this work. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

I'm doing this in Access. My tables look like:

```
Table P
ID           Name
1            Alice
2            Bob


Table I
ID           P ID       Type
1            1          a
2            1          b
3            1          a
4            1          b
5            1          b
6            1          b
7            2          b
```

And I want to return

```
ID         First of Type         Count of I        Count of a        Count of b
1          a                     6                 2                 4
2          b                     1                 0                 1
```

Hope this makes sense. I tried to use the "union all" syntax but no luck with what I'm trying so far.

Comment: Please post sample data structure. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Well first, you must add 2 more condition in your select, and then, try with an LEFT JOIN I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCTROW 
    P.ID, First(I.Type) AS [First Of Type], 
    Count(*) AS [Count Of I],
    SUM(CASE P.ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count of Alice],
    SUM(CASE P.ID WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count of Bob]
FROM 
    P INNER JOIN I ON P.[ID] = I.[P ID]
GROUP BY P.ID;
```

Or specific to access to those who use it:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCTROW 
    P.ID, First(I.Type) AS [First Of Type], 
    Count(*) AS [Count Of I],
    SUM(IIF (I.Type = "a", 1, 0)) AS [Count of a],
    SUM(IIF (I.Type = "b", 1, 0)) AS [Count of b]
FROM 
    P INNER JOIN I ON P.[ID] = I.[P ID]
GROUP BY P.ID;
```

Of course, this ONLY covers Alice and Bob, and does not really allow for the pivot query, which is what it seems like you're looking for. I'd recommend looking into pivot queries.

Comment: I will look into the pivot query - thanks. Unfortunately, it looks like MS-Access doesn't support the CASE statement although I found a suggestion to look into the IIF or SWITCH statements as a replacement so I'll try those. Thanks again.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Although in access, you need: SELECT 
    DISTINCTROW 
    P.ID, First(I.Type) AS [First Of Type], 
    Count(*) AS [Count Of I],
    SUM(IIF (I.Type = "a", 1, 0)) AS [Count of a],
    SUM(IIF (Intervention.Type = "b", 1, 0)) AS [Count of b]
FROM 
     P INNER JOIN I ON P.[ID] = I.[P ID]
GROUP BY P.ID;

Comment: Great, I approved the update. I initially saw the SQL and missed that it was Access, so I used SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what your asking so if you can explain a little more what you want that would be helpful but think what your heading towards is using a `union all`

```
[A query]
union all
[another query]
```

e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROW P.ID, First(I.Type) AS [First Of Type], Count(*) AS [Count Of I]
FROM P INNER JOIN I ON P.[ID] = I.[P ID]
GROUP BY P.ID 
union all
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ColumnA
FROM WHERE_EVER
WHERE A_CONDITION;
```

Comment: I posted tables as an example. Can you suggest how I'd use union all for those specific examples? I'm not able to get the syntax correct. Can I refer to values from my first query in the second query when using union all?